# Tampermonkey/Javascript: Looking for a way to alert users to URLs in a page

Tags: javascript, userscripts, tampermonkey

In my job, I have to check webpages/websites for specific URLs and flag them for customer service review if I find any of those URLs.

A co-worker who's no longer with the company wrote a script to automate this, but the code is a hot mess.

I learned this, when I went into the script and tried to add new pages to search for.

My knowledge of javascript is pretty limited, but I mostly got around by reading tutorials and trial and error.

Here, though, I'm stumped.

Here's the code in question:

(I won't show the includes and excludes, because of privacy/data privacy reasons.)

CODE:

```
// Links
var read = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Belongs to Links
var link;

// Start Youtube-Link Search
var alertbox1 = 0;
var alertbox2 = 0;
var alertbox3 = 0;
var alertbox4 = 0;
var alertbox5 = 0;
var alertbox6 = 0;
var alertbox7 = 0;

// End Youtube-Link Search


for(var n=0; n < read.length; n++)
{
    link = read[n];


if(link.href.indexOf("http://www.youtube.com") == 0)
{
    link.style.color="#ff0000";
    link.style.borderBottom="5px dotted red";

    if(alertbox1 == 0)
    {
        alertbox1++;
    }

    if(alertbox1 == 1)
    {
        alert("Youtube Link!");
        alertbox1++;
    }

}


if(link.href.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com") == 0)
{
    link.style.color="#ff0000";
    link.style.borderBottom="5px dotted red";

    if(alertbox2 == 0)
    {
        alertbox2++;
    }

    if(alertbox2 == 1)
    {
        alert("Youtube Link!");
        alertbox2++;
    }

}


if(link.href.indexOf("http://youtube.com") == 0)
{
    link.style.color="#ff0000";
    link.style.borderBottom="5px dotted red";

    if(alertbox3 == 0)
    {
        alertbox3++;
    }

    if(alertbox3 == 1)
    {
        alert("Youtube Link!");
        alertbox3++;
    }

}


if(link.href.indexOf("https://youtube.com") == 0)
{
    link.style.color="#ff0000";
    link.style.borderBottom="5px dotted red";

    if(alertbox4 == 0)
    {
        alertbox4++;
    }

    if(alertbox4 == 1)
    {
        alert("Youtube Link!");
        alertbox4++;
    }

}


if(link.href.indexOf("http://www.youtu.be") == 0)
{
    link.style.color="#ff0000";
    link.style.borderBottom="5px dotted red";

    if(alertbox5 == 0)
    {
        alertbox5++;
    }

    if(alertbox5 == 1)
    {
        alert("Youtube Link!");
        alertbox5++;
    }

}


if(link.href.indexOf("https://www.youtu.be") == 0)
{
    link.style.color="#ff0000";
    link.style.borderBottom="5px dotted red";

    if(alertbox6 == 0)
    {
        alertbox6++;
    }

    if(alertbox6 == 1)
    {
        alert("Youtube Link!");
        alertbox6++;
    }

}


if(link.href.indexOf("http://youtu.be") == 0)
{
    link.style.color="#ff0000";
    link.style.borderBottom="5px dotted red";

    if(alertbox7 == 0)
    {
        alertbox7++;
    }

    if(alertbox7 == 1)
    {
        alert("Youtube Link!");
        alertbox7++;
    }

}
```

I tried to 'optimize' this a bit and let it look for wildcards,to cut down on entires (e.g.: "*://*.youtube.*) but that doesn't work/that stops the script from working. But I feel that it should be possible to combine looking for http and https, as well as .com, .de and .be links without having to write each possibility as its own etry. Am I right?

And if I am:

Is there a better, cleaner way to do this, so that when the script finds a URL inside the active page/site, it throws up a warning box for the user to see and click away?

Thank you, to any- and everybody being able and willing to contiribute any pointers/help/hints/advice.

Comment: You can’t use wildcards with indexOf. What you can do is f.e. not look at the full `href` property of the link to begin with, but the `hostname` part only. You could simply check (still using indexOf) if that contains `youtube.` or `.youtube.` - the latter of course won’t catch anything without subdomain. If you need it more sophisticated than that, you could look into regular expressions to use wildcards. Or at least use an array of several different “spellings” of host names in YT links that you can loop over (instead of repeating the same code just with different values multiple times.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out `regex`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

I will warn you that this will take some effort to get used to with. This site: http://regexr.com will definitely help you if you decide to use regex.

A regex expression that will match all the cases that you've specified could be declared and used like this:

```
var regex=/https?://(www\.)?youtu\.?be(\.com)?/gi

if (regex.exec(string_to_test)){
   //show the alert message
}
```

...and welcome to S/O! I'd recommend splitting the second part of your question off into a separate one. Happy coding!